# Can't add the platform in ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm creating a ionic project and when add platform it shows platform android already added.
**Ionic platform android**

Comment: You can use command **ionic platform rm android** to remove the platform or delete platforms folder and run add command again

Comment: It means android platform is already added.Then why are you add this platform again?

Comment: Actually first it shows one folder it has platform folder,but now it doesn't have any folder in that project.Only shows the message platform is already added.